# Queue implementation using std::forward_list returning an error

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, iterator, queue

Returned this runtime Error

```
$/usr/bin/ld: QueueusingSLL: _ZSt4cout: invalid version 2 (max 0)

$/usr/bin/ld: QueueusingSLL: error adding symbols: bad value 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Also, How can you return an iterator from a class member function?
See `auto iterator()` function inside code.

Source code

```
#include<iostream>     // std::cout
#include<forward_list> // std::singly linked list
#include<iterator>     //// std::iterator,next(is a random iterator)
//#include <algorithm> // std::for_each loop
using namespace std;

class Queue
{
private:
   forward_list<int> list;

public:
   Queue()
   {}

   Queue(int firstElem) {
      enqueue(firstElem);
   }

   //Return the size of Queue
   int size()
   {
      forward_list<int>::iterator first = list.begin();
      forward_list<int>::iterator last = list.end();
      return std::distance(first, last);
   }

   //Return whether or not the queue us empty
   void isEmpty()
   {
      std::cout << "Queue " << (list.empty() ? "is empty" : "is not empty") << std::endl;
   }

   // Peek the top of the stack without removing an element
   // Returns 0 if queue is empty.
   int peek()
   {
      if (list.empty() == 1)
         return 0;
      return list.front();
   }

   //Add an element at back(end or tail) of queue:enqueue
   void enqueue(int Elem)
   {
      auto pos = list.begin();
      while (std::next(pos) != list.end()) ++pos;
      list.insert_after(pos, Elem);
   }

   //Remove an element from front of queue:dequeue
   int dequeue()
   {
      if (list.empty() == 1) return 0;
      list.pop_front();
      return 1; //1 means success
   }

   void display()
   {
      cout << endl << "Elements in Queue x";
      for (forward_list<int>::iterator i = list.begin(); i != list.end(); i++)
      {
         cout << endl << "\t" << *i;
      }
      cout << endl << endl;
   }

   /*auto iterator()
    {
        return list.iterator();
    }*/
};


int main()
{
   Queue Q1, Q2(5);
   Q1.isEmpty();
   Q2.isEmpty();
   cout << endl << "sizeofQ1   " << Q1.size() << endl << "sizeofQ2     " << Q2.size() << endl << endl;
   Q1.enqueue(10);
   Q1.enqueue(20);
   Q1.enqueue(30);
   Q1.enqueue(40);
   Q1.enqueue(50);
   Q1.enqueue(60);
   Q1.display();
   Q2.display();
   cout << endl << "sizeofQ1   " << Q1.size() << endl << endl;
   Q1.dequeue();
   Q1.dequeue();
   Q1.display();
   cout << endl << "sizeofQ1   " << Q1.size() << endl << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you want to inseart end of the container, would have been better to use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), instead of `std::forward_list`. Then simply use [`std::vector::push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) or [`std::vector::emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) as per. To get the first and last element, use then [`std::vector::front`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/front) and [`std::vector::back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back) respectively.

---

To your problem: Your `enqueue` function doe not handle the `list` empty case. You need

```
void enqueue(int Elem)
{
   if (list.empty())  // for the empty list case
   {
      list.push_front(Elem);
      return; // done here
   }

   auto pos = list.begin();
   while (std::next(pos) != list.end())
      ++pos;
   list.insert_after(pos, Elem);
}
```

---

> How can you return an iterator from a class member function?

Like in the standards containers, you need to return the `begin` and `end` iterator by providing the suitable members. For instance

```
auto begin() const noexcept {
   return list.begin();
}

auto end() const noexcept {
   return list.end();
}
```

However, `auto` returns are only possible since [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14). In [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), you need to mention the return type explicitly. Thanks to *[trailing return](https://arne-mertz.de/2016/11/trailing-return-types-everywhere/)*, by which you could

```
auto begin() const noexcept -> decltype(list.begin()) // trailing return
{
   return list.begin();
}

auto end() const noexcept -> decltype(list.end()) // trailing return
{
   return list.end();
}
```

---

As a side note, [please do not practice with `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: good answer. I want only to explicit that begin and end are two methods of list. ".iterator()" is not.